# Gitlab CI rules keyword mark job as blocking instead of skip when using when keyword

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Until now I'm using gitlab-ci job to deploy in prod with `when: manual` but I recently have requirement to auto-deploy in prod when schedule job is running (that will add specific variable)

Thus I changed `when: manual` with `rules` keyword as following:

```
rules:
  # deploy if schedule is triggered and thus variable is present
  - if: '$DEPLOYMENT_SCHEDULE == "true"'
    when: always
  # Else (if master branch) keep job as manual (as before)
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
    when: manual
```

However the pipeline view has changed a bit, because:

1. When I was using `when: manual`, pipeline is considered as *passed*

[image: when manual]

2. With `rules:` (when merge on master without `DEPLOYMENT_SCHEDULE`), pipeline is considered as *blocked*

[image: with rules]

---

Is there something I miss? How can I have same pipeline result with `rules` keyword?

Answer (score 2):

@kakawait I believe there's a bug report open on this issue at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/30075

> **What is the current bug behavior?**
>
> Shows the pipeline status as skipped even though the only job included is a manual action.
>
> **What is the expected correct behavior?**
>
> The pipeline status should reflect the manual action status.

Comment: From what I understand on issue report is talking about the pipeline (=! jobs) is skipped. However on my use case in no cases (with when or rules) pipeline is skipped, is succeed (with when) or blocked (with rules)

Comment: Did you create an issue ? I'm interesting in solving this too.

Comment: Not really, I've changed workflow and I'm not using rules anymore so I don't know if still an issue